# How to write HQL query in hibernate to delete all rows without deleting table?

Tags: java, hibernate

How to write HQL query in hibernate to delete all rows without deleting table?
and
How to delete all table in database using HQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table is called `your_table` which corresponds to the `Entity` class `Your_Table`, the following should work:

```
@Entity @Table(name="your_table")
public class Your_Table {

    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    // columns go here
    // getters and setters
}

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("delete from Your_Table").executeUpdate();
```

If you want to drop all tables in your database, you will have to use raw SQL commands.  HQL was not intended for creating/deleting tables, but rather for manipulating `Entity` objects created from tables.  If you really want to drop all tables in your database, you can just drop the database itself and then re-create it using raw SQL:

```
DROP DATABASE your_database;
CREATE DATABASE your_database;
```